# Pandas count true boolean values per row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe `df` which looks like the following:

| num1 | num2 | bool1 | bool2 | bool3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 20 | 30 | True | False | True |
| 10 | 5 | False | True | True |

For each row I want to count the number of `True` values for a specific subset of the boolean columns, say `bool2` and `bool3`. So the desired output would look like this:

| num1 | num2 | bool1 | bool2 | bool3 | count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 20 | 30 | True | False | True | 1 |
| 10 | 5 | False | True | True | 2 |

In SQL I used to do this with something like CARDINALITY(bool2, bool3). Trying to figure out if there is a simple way to do something like that in Pandas.

Comment: See also:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33823091/python-pandas-counting-the-frequency-of-a-specific-value-in-each-row-of-datafra
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49557895/replace-specific-values-in-pandas-dataframe

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apply `sum` over columns axis:

```
df['count'] = df[['bool2', 'bool3']].sum(axis=1)
```

Output:

```
>>> df
   num1  num2  bool1  bool2  bool3  count
0    20    30   True  False   True      1
1    10     5  False   True   True      2
```